# Logic: Proving that ~(P->Q) and P^~Q are equivalent

Tags: logic

Informally, I realize that `~(P->Q)` is the same as `P^~Q`, since the only way that the original conditional `P->Q` would be false is if we had both `P^~Q`.

I think that given `~(P->Q)`, the next step would be to assume `~(P^~Q)` and try to obtain `P^~Q` via proof by contradiction, but after this step, I am not sure how to proceed.

The system I am using is Fitch. Unfortunately, I cannot use AnaCon or TautCon, nor can I use truth tables.

Comment: Why not just a truth table?

Comment: Professor will not allow TautCon or the use of truth tables.

Comment: Are you using a textbook? If so, which one?

Comment: Also duplicate of [proving $\lnot (A \rightarrow B) \vdash A \land \lnot B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227589/proving-lnot-a-rightarrow-b-vdash-a-land-lnot-b)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No words needed.  A picture speaks a thousand words!

Comment: Wish it were the case, unfortunately my professor will not allow truth tables, nor the use of TautCon.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726708/how-to-solve-p-%E2%86%92-q-p-q-by-natural-deduction?noredirect=1&lq=1